# Making many offset lines that are always a set distance from the previous

Tags: qgis, python, line, buffer, offset

I've discovered the Offset lines tool in Vector Geometry, which allows you to make a parallel line next to the input at a specified offset distance. What I would like to do is specify how many subsequent offset lines I want. As of now, you can only create one offset for each feature in the input layer.

I understand you could probably loop this, but is there a more efficient way of doing this? An alternate function? I included an image to illustrate what I'd like to do.

[image]

Comment: How are you creating the offset currently? Do you need a geometry or new layer, or does a symbology suffice?

Comment: I would like each new offset line to be a separate feature in one layer, as each needs data to be appended to it later.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at the tool `array offset lines`. It should do exactly what you need, and using data defined override you may use attributes to specify how many offest lines each existing line should have.

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly it. Thank you so much.